# How to disable triggers from nesting/recursing when accessing the same table

Tags: mysql, trigger

So I have this data

```
+----+----------+-------+---------------+----------------+------------+--------+
| id | date     | accid | accid_currbal | Action         | Desc       | Amount |
| 1  | 05/06/17 | 1     | 7777          | Create Account | some desc… | 7777   |
| 2  | 05/06/17 | 1     | 32091         | Add Funds      | some desc… | 24324  |
| 3  | 05/06/17 | 1     | 32100         | Add Funds      | some desc… | 9      |
| 4  | 05/06/17 | 1     | 32600         | Add Funds      | some desc… | 500    |
+----+----------+-------+---------------+----------------+------------+--------+
```

And an BEFORE_UPDATE trigger that accesses this table when it fires

```
CREATE ..... TRIGGER 
`db_moneytracker`.`transactions_BEFORE_UPDATE` BEFORE UPDATE ON 
`transactions` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE adj INT;

if (old.amount <> new.amount && old.accid = new.accid) then
set adj = new.amount - old.amount;

update transactions set accid_curr_accbalance = accid_curr_accbalance + adj 
where accid = new.accid and `date` >= new.date;

elseif (old.accid <> new.accid) then
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
                SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'IDs unchangeable';
end if;
END
```

But produces an error when updated

```
1442: Can't update table 'transactions' in stored function/trigger because 
it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

I think I understood what it meant so... I want the trigger not to fire the UPDATE is fired by THIS trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an update statement:

In a "before update" trigger, you can directly *change* any of the values in the new row.

```
if ( old.amount <> new.amount && old.accid = new.accid ) then
   set adj = new.amount - old.amount ; 
   set new.accid_curr_accbalance = new.accid_curr_accbalance + adj ; 
else
   . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

Change: `date >= new.date;` --> `date = new.date;`  and add `SET new.accid_curr_accbalance = ...` instead.